# Missing "libiconv.h" when crosscompiling for Windows with mingw on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, cross-compiling

I have been working on a program in SDL and I would like to send it to my friends who only run a Windows environment. I have done some reading and found that I should use mingw to cross-compile for Windows. The binary I found and compiled was x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++, however I am getting some issues getting my program to compile. Using the following command I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ sapphire.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2` -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -std=c++11
fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
```

While I realize I should make a makefile eventually, I am not going to do that now.

I tried installing iconv (Version 1.15) from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/) and used the following commands to compile it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make all
```

My iconv.h is located in /usr/include but if I include that I get another error for missing gnu/stubs.h and if I include that then I get a myriad of errors that I'm not sure how/if I could fix seen [here](https://pastebin.com/2y7S9z3F). Does anyone know how I could perhaps fix this? I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I pretty sure that when you use _pkg-config_ this way it will give you the libraries and include files of the host system, and I would guess that even if compiling would succeed, linking would fail. In the above case you actually compiled and installed _iconv_ in the host system with the host compiler and  not for mingw.

How things are done properly is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986715/mingw-cross-compiling-on-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pkg-config with mingw in a crosscompiler environment but you should take care to where pkg-config searches for his .pc files.

I'm assuming your mingw crosscompiler is installed in /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32, change it to the installation path where his "include" and "lib" subdirectories are.

Provided SDL windows developement package is installed in the same prefix on your computer and the installation has a correct pkg-config .pc file you can do:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig
```

and then try pkg-config from the command line:

```
pkg-config sdl2 --cflags
```

This should point you to some path inside /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32, if it does your compilation will be successful.

Please note that if you want to compile a package for crosscompile (like the iconv you tried to compile) you should add to the ./configure script parameters:

```
--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/xx86_64-w64-mingw32
```

... and this may work or not, depending the package support the mingw32 compiler or not.

The way you compiled iconv built another linux version of it in /usr/local!

**NOTE**: As far as I know Ubuntu does not provide a windows package for SDL2, while other linux distro do, so you'll need to cross-compile SDL2 with the option I gave before you can compile your code. SDL2 **does** support cross-compilation using mingw.